# Blenders video sequence editor VS. Audacity for arranging audio

Tags: video-sequence-editor

To people who have used both Audacity and Blenders video sequence editor:
Which do you think is better for splicing, rearanging, etc. for your projects audio track?

Comment: Use this add-on for combining both software programs: https://github.com/tin2tin/audacity_tools_for_blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a commercial Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) from PreSonus called StudioOne  However I do use both the VSE and Audacity for arranging simple audio, and I would recommend a workflow that uses both:

1. Do most of your audio editing and arranging in Audacity.  It has a more complete tool kit for audio editing; especially for handling multiple channels.
2. Use audacity to downmix the audio to stereo and export the stereo in a lossless format that you like to work with.
3. Use the VSE to splice the stereo together with the video.

Answer (score 0):

Dubbing (as well as sound mixing and editing) of video should, in my opinion, be done at the step where editing and color correction is involved: in post-production.

Blender is not a professional video editing program and its capabilities are extremely limited.

I recommend [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/at/products/davinciresolve) (free of charge in the basic version!). There you have all the necessary editing options for audio and the ability to play it all in sync with your video.